# ISA Net connection goes down periodically

Tags: isa-server, internet

Thanks for taking the time to help out.

I have been working at the IT Dept of a company for the past 6 months, thus there are a lot of things I don't know and am not sure about.
Yet I can verify/seek information needed to solve this problem.

The issue we are having is that everyday, our network looses internet connection.
We go over to the ISA server, and it doesn't have internet access.
If we restart the server, then we're back up and running like nothing had happened.

I am at a complete loss on where or how to start diagnosing/troubleshooting this problem.
The issue isn't tied down to a certain part of the day, as it occurs any point in the day/night.

Maybe ISA is working fine, yet its connection outside is what's giving us problems?
The ISA server is connected to a Cisco 800 modem.

Could there be something I could check or verify, or a set of processes to keep an eye out for?

Again, I know the information is vague, yet I don't know where to start.
If you would like more information on our system setup, let me know and I'll find out and later post it here.

I have no experience with ISA servers, just a recent n00b with CentOS (unrelated to work).

Thank you very much for your time and help... greatly appreciated!

.AJ

Answer (score 0):

Start with the logs under the Event Viewer to see if there is anything that is blatantly logging errors during the outages.